# Escape HTML on custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mathjax

I have a Custom directive that renders strings with latex using MathJax.js, here's the code.

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    skipStartupTypeset: true,
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
      processEscapes: true
    }
});
MathJax.Hub.Configured();

angular.module('mathjaxModule', [])

.directive("mathjaxBind", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: ["$scope", "$element", "$attrs", function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch($attrs.mathjaxBind, function(value) {
                $element.text(value == undefined ? "" : value);
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, $element[0]]);
            });
        }]
    };
});
```

and you use it like this:
`<span mathjax-bind="textToRender"></span>`

This directive is very convenient because I can combine text with MathJax expressions, and as long as the math expressions are within `$$`, everything renders fine. Text as text and math expressions using MathJax.

The problem is that some of those strings include also HTML, and I can't seem to use `ng-bind-html` when I'm using my custom directive.

I tried something like this without success:

`<span mathjax-bind="textToRender" ng-bind-html="textToRender"></span>`

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the concept. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need, and I found the answer from here: http://blog.datacamp.com/mathjax-binding-in-angular-js/

Here is my code:

```
.directive('mathjax',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $scope.$watch($attrs.ngBindHtml, function () {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub,$element[0]]);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then use it like: `<span ng-bind-html="textToRender" mathjax></span>`